# Tiempo de respuesta de Mysql algo lenta

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, hosting

Contrate un servidor de hosting las especificaciones del servidor son las siguientes.

```
256 Mb de ram
Un nucleo de procesador
10 Gb de espacio interno
El clock es de 2.2GHz y usa el 25% de un Nucleo
Es un servidor compartido
```

Resulta que al intentar consultar/agregar/editar alguna tabla este tarda mucho. Esto se debe a las especificaciones del servidor?

Normalmente tarda entre 5 a 10 segundos por operación. 
Cuando la base de datos era local era inmediato.

Comment: Puede ser la conexión. Mysql es muy rápido, dudo q sea la configuración.
La que seria importante saber es que tipo de consulta estas haciendo, que cantidad de registros tiene la tabla, tiene indices?

Comment: La tabla a la que le hago select tiene un solo registro lo probé con una coneccion de 100mb y con otra de 10mb y las dos tardan lo mismo, añadir registros a la tabla también tarda lo mismo  (o más tiempo) consulto esto porque si es el proveedor que es muy lento lo ideal sería mejorarlo pero no quiero gastar más y que siga andando igual.

Comment: ahora miré bien la configuración. 256Mb? ese dato seguro esta bien?

 Configuración minima para que MySQL funcione bien:
    CPU: Intel Core or Xeon 3GHz (or Dual Core 2GHz) or equal AMD CPU
    Cores: Single (Dual/Quad Core is recommended)
    RAM: 4 GB (6 GB recommended)

Comment: Si, esas son las especificaciones que me dicen de mi planm ya veo.. sin duda es ese el problema.

Comment: Seguramente entonces sea un problema de hardware. Mysql requiere 4GB minimo y recomienda 6Gb.